# Using Pywinauto to automate ABBYY, I get "ElementNotFoundError"

Tags: python, pywinauto, abbyy

I am trying to use pywinauto to use the progam ABBYY FineReader. I am using the following code (based on this YouTube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4E4IOIC63s):

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

Application(backend = 'uia').start(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ABBYY FineReader 15\FineReaderOCR.exe', timeout = 5)

app = Application(backend = 'uia').connect(title = 'Untitled Project - ABBYY FineReader PDF 15 OCR Editor')
```

After running the last line, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ariel\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_6460\814936370.py", line 1, in <module>
    app = Application(backend = 'uia').connect(title = 'Untitled Project - ABBYY FineReader PDF 15 OCR Editor')

  File "C:\Users\ariel\anaconda3\envs\pdf_parser_env\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 997, in connect
    self.process = findwindows.find_element(**kwargs).process_id

  File "C:\Users\ariel\anaconda3\envs\pdf_parser_env\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)

ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Untitled Project - ABBYY FineReader PDF 15 OCR Editor', 'backend': 'uia', 'visible_only': False}
```

When I do the canonical Notepad example, I don't get any error:

```
note = Application(backend = 'uia').start(r'notepad.exe').connect(title= 'Untitled - Notepad', timeout = 2)
```

I've played around with the code using other postings with similar problems on here and other forums, but I can't figure out what exactly might be going on and I can't get around this error. Is there something wrong with my code or are there some programs that won't allow you to use pywinauto?

Comment: Please check texts returned by `print([w.window_text() for w in Desktop(backend="uia").windows()])` Sometimes title text contains invisible symbols which fails direct comparison. Also `title_re` is an additional option for dynamic title.

Comment: And please use `timeout` param in `connect` method call explicitly. Default timeout is zero instead of usual 5 sec. It's a known issue in current release.

Comment: These did the trick, I think it was the invisible symbols problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Based on the comments by Vasily Ryabov, I used

```
print([w.window_text() for w in Desktop(backend="uia").windows()])
```

And copied and pasted the name of the window and added the timeout option for good measure:

```
app = Application(backend = 'uia').connect(title = 'Untitled project - ABBYY FineReader PDF 15 OCR Editor', timeout = 5)
```

I now see I had simply capitalized "project" unnecessarily.